# form validation javascript for specific digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

i want to put another condition where mobile No. should contain 8 digits only starting with 5. (ex:52024050). any help

```js
function formValidation() {
  var mobile = document.forms["form"]["mobile"].value;

  // red expression 
  var checkNumbers = /^[0-9 ]+$/;

  if (mobile == null || mobile == "") {
    error[error.length] = ("Enter your mobile number");
    document.form.mobile.focus();
    $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "blue");;
  } else if (mobile != null || mobile != "") {
    if (!checkNumbers.test(mobile)) {
      error[error.length] = ("Enter Only numeric Characters for mobile phone");
      document.form.mobile.focus();
      $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "blue");
    }
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return formValidation()" action="process.html">

  Mobile phone:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile">

  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex as follow

```
/^5[0-9]{7}$/
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/wK2qU6/1)

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `5`: Matches 5 once
3. `[0-9]{7}`: Matches any number between 0 and 9 exactly 7 times
4. `$`: End of line

I'd suggest to use the regex on element itself in `pattern` attribute and `maxlength`.

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid, span {
  color: red;
}
span {
  display: none;
}
input:invalid + span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="5[0-9]{7}" maxlength="8" />
<span>Enter Only numeric Characters for mobile phone.</span>
```

As jQuery is included on page, I'd recommend to use it for DOM manipulation and event handling.

HTML:

```
<form name="form" action="process.html">
    Mobile phone:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" pattern="5[0-9]{7}" maxlength="8">

    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mobilePattern = /^5[0-9]{7}$/;
$('form[name="form"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();

    if (!mobilePattern.test(mobile)) {
        $('#mobile').css('background', 'blue').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: pattern doesn't work properly with Safari and IE prior to 10, I wouldn't encourage using it right now.

Comment: @MateoBarahona It should be accompanied by the JS code to check the format. I'm not saying that use **`pattern`** only. If that is supported by browser JS will not be called again and again as browser's native validation will work, if not then it'll be simply ignored as custom attribute.

Comment: ok, I couldn't see the javascript code when I commented and I was afraid supergirl would think she didn't need JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
var checkMobile = /^5[0-9]{7}$/;
```

`^5` => starts with 5

`[0-9]{7}$` => followed and ending by 7 numbers